# How to determine if an WPF Datagrid item is selected, and bind to the true/false result

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I feel like this should be easy, but I am stumped.

I am trying to bind a ComboBox.IsEnabled property to something like "Is an item currently selected on the DataGrid" property using MVVM. This way if no item is selected on the DataGrid, the ComboBox will be disabled.

Is there a DataGrid property that registers True/False when an item is selected, or do I need to do something with the SelectedItems.Count property?

I am trying to do this with as little code as possible before I write a converter or custom property.

Comment: Not sufficient information, MVVM or codebehind?

Comment: MVVM. Sorry I will edit my question.

Comment: Add some code of what you tried so far

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no inbuilt property which will say there is one item selected in `DataGrid`. Instead you can Bind a property to `SelectedItem` of your `DataGrid` and Check for `SelectedItem` is `null`.

for Example:

```
 <DataGrid
        ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfitems}" 
        SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentItem, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Then your VM

```
    private object _CurrentItem;
    public object CurrentItem
    {
        get
        {
            return _CurrentItem;
        }
        set

        {
            _CurrentDocument = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
            //Make your logic for your combobox binding.
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

//xaml

```
<DataGrid SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedModelItem}"/> 
<ComboBox IsEnabled={Binding IsItemSelected } />
```

//VM (You will need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged in your ViewModel)

```
public bool IsItemSelected { get {return null != SelectedModelItem; }

public YourModelType SelectedModelItem{
get{
   return selectedModelItem;
}
set{
   selectedModelItem = value;
   OnPropertyChanged();   
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a converter to solve the above question. Thank you everybody for your suggestions. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing a property, before I implemented this.

XAML

```
<Control.Resources>
    <local:ItemToBoolConverter x:Key="ItemToBoolConverter"/>
</Control.Resources>

 <ComboBox IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=dataGrid, Path=SelectedItems.Count, Converter={StaticResource ItemToBoolConverter}}">
```

Code Behind

```
public class ItemToBoolConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        try
        {
            int? itemCount = value as int?;
            if (itemCount < 1)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch { return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue; }
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

}
```

Comment: Good Approach. Only thing is that you need to specify an `ElementName`. rest is all good.

Answer (score 0):

view

```
<Window x:Class="..."
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:cvt="clr-namespace:TestTelerikColumnFooter"
    Width="300" Height="300" 
    >
<Window.Resources>
    <cvt:SelectionConverter x:Key="SelectionConverter" />
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ComboBox Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Coll1}" IsEnabled="{Binding SelectedPerson, Converter={StaticResource SelectionConverter}}" DisplayMemberPath="FirstName" Margin="6"/>
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Coll2}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson}" Margin="6"/>

</Grid>
```

MainViewmodel:

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public class Person
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public float Val { get; set; }

    }


    private object _selectedPerson;
    public object SelectedPerson
    {
        get { return _selectedPerson; }
        set
        {
            _selectedPerson = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedPerson");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private bool _isItemSelected;
    public bool IsItemSelected
    {
        get { return _isItemSelected; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _isItemSelected) 
                return;
            _isItemSelected = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsItemSelected");
        }
    }


    private ObservableCollection<Person> _coll1;
    public ObservableCollection<Person> Coll1
    {
        get
        {
            return _coll1 ?? (_coll1 = new ObservableCollection<Person>());
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Person> _coll2;
    public ObservableCollection<Person> Coll2
    {
        get
        {
            return _coll2 ?? (_coll2 = new ObservableCollection<Person>());
        }
    } 

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Coll1.Add(
        new Person
        {
            FirstName = "TOUMI",
            LastName = "Redhouane",
            Val = 12.2f
        });

        Coll1.Add(
        new Person
        {
            FirstName = "CHERCHALI",
            LastName = "Karim",
            Val = 15.3f
        });

        Coll2.Add(
        new Person
        {
            FirstName = "TOUMI",
            LastName = "Djamel",
            Val = 12.2f
        });
        Coll2.Add(
        new Person
        {
            FirstName = "CHERCHALI",
            LastName = "Redha",
            Val = 12.2f
        });
    }


}
```

MainWindow:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MainViewModel();
    }
}
```

converter :

```
 public class SelectionConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {

        return value != null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```